# Branch.io - iFrame in Custom Deepview Not Working

Tags: branch, deep-linking, branch.io, ios-universal-links

I've been trying to setup a simple iFrame element in my custom branch deepview. When trying to save, I get a security vulnerability error and the `src` value in the iFrame element is removed. I thought this was possible as per this Branch.io Blog Post: https://blog.branch.io/custom-deepviews-for-your-mobile-app/

Any insight on this matter would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

The reason that you are observing this is since we disabled JavaScript in deepviews for some security concerns. If you have a specific use-case, we can enable Javascript for your deepview from the backend, for which you'll need to share your Deepview name and Deepview key so that we can enable JS for it. You can share these details by reaching out to our [Support team](https://help.branch.io/using-branch/page/submit-a-ticket).